# getting command cim not found error in drupal while using drush commands

Tags: drupal, drush, cim

drush cim error and also database is not shown to be connected when running drush st.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnzgh.png

Answer (score 0):

first you need to run your server (xampp or whatever you use), then
check on your settings.php if you have your database connection right.
check on my mysql admin page if you have your database created.